# Converting a []byte containing strings into decimal values

Tags: go

I am trying to take a string and convert each value in the string into the decimal ASCII value. I first converted the string into the []byte type and i want to take each element of the []byte and convert it into decimal ASCII value. Here is my code:

```
myArray := []byte(password) // convert string into []byte type
NumArray := [len(password)]int // create second []int type to store the    converted []byte elements
for i := 0; i < len(myArray); i++{
                                /*  I need some help to convert each element in myArray into ASCII decimal value and then store it into 
                                    NumArray.
                                */
fmt.Printf("%d\n", myArray[i]) //prints out what the converted values should be
fmt.Print(NumArray[i]) //prints out the stored converted value for comparison
}
```

Edit: the string is supposed to be a password and so can contain any value

Comment: So, you have told us what you are doing. Is there a question you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast `byte` to `int` like this:

```
NumArray[i] = int(myArray[i])
```